# Using mysql user-defined variable with group by condition

Tags: mysql, variables, group-by

I am trying to store the result of a sum in a variable to use it afterward in the query with no success so far.

- I've tried that and it worked just like I expected : `SELECT @pos := 'titi' "c1", @pos "c2";`

`titi | titi`

- When I try to do it with a group by function it just doesn't work anymore, it sets my variable to the last processed function.

`SELECT c1, @titi := SUM(c2), @titi 
FROM (SELECT 1 "c1",2 "c2" UNION SELECT 2,3 UNION SELECT 1,4) t
GROUP BY c1;`

**Actual Output** :

> 1, 6, 3
>
> 2, 3, 3

**Desired Output** :

> 1, 6, 6
>
> 2, 3, 3

What can I do to make the variable keep its value on a per-row basis ?

Comment: the syntax of your queries is incorrect. And it is not clear what you are trying to achieve: do you want to store anything to use in a following query? Why not just use a subquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I recall correctly, the problem here is that the value of the column that does not contain an aggregation function is computed when the first row of the group is processed, while the assignment `@var:=SUM` takes place when the aggregated value is computed.

That is you either need just to repeat the aggregation function in the other context, or if the aggregated function is rather complex, and you do not want to repeat: a) put everything in a subquery, b) use something like `IF(COUNT(*), @var, @var)` (which looks rather hacky)

P.S. Your queries seem to be invalid, since column names shoud be quoted with backquotes.